# How can i access the same variable in php from different if statements?

Tags: php

I am trying to access the same variable from different if statement. How can I do it? I will show what I want to do.

```
if{}
   if{}
   else{ $upfile }
else{}
```

I have this kind of structure in my php. What I want to do is accessing $upfile in the last else for the insert statement. How can I do it?

Any answer is helpful.

Comment: That bit of code by itself makes it very hard to answer. Does that mean `$upfile` is only being defined inside the `if..if..else` clause? Generally though: Use *logic* to make sure variables are what they should be. It's not about "accessing variables", it's about doing things in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
$upfile = 'test';
if{}
   if{}
   else{ $upfile }
else{}
```

Comment: I get it. But it does not solve my problem although. Never mind. Thanks for the answer.